# document.ready() crashing all my scripts when trying preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a project for school and I'm giving the site some finishing touches, I tried doing a preloader today from some tutorials with CSS and jQuery and it works good so far; until it only reads only specific parts of the `main.js` I have.

The burger-menu and the back to top button stop working.
This is [my codepen](https://codepen.io/reardgjoni/pen/qyzKBe).

```
<section id="preloader">
  <div id="dots">
  <p>Please wait, programmer is sleeping . . .</p>
  <p>Please wait, programmer is sleeping . . .</p>
  <p>Please wait, programmer is sleeping . . .</p>
  <div class="dot" style="animation-name:preloader_1;"></div>
  <div class="dot" style="animation-name:preloader_2;"></div>
  <div class="dot" style="animation-name:preloader_3;"></div>
  <div class="dot" style="animation-name:preloader_4;"></div></div>
  <div id="bg_left" class="pre_half"></div>
  <div id="bg_right" class="pre_half"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dots').delay(950).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $('#bg_left').animate({left: '-50%'}, 600);
        $('#bg_right').animate({right: '-50%'}, 600), function() {
            $('preloader').fadeOut(10);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting this error on the console :

> TypeError: arrowLeft is null[Weitere Informationen]

But only because there's only one `main.js` for several .html's.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read the error — you’re still getting some elements before the DOM is loaded. The `<section id="preloader">` is above the entire screen, which is why you can’t click on anything. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] (this means, your _JavaScript code must be in the question itself_).

Comment: Im getting this : TypeError: arrowLeft is null[Weitere Informationen], but only because thers only one main.js for several .html's.
So you think I should put the whole section somewhere else or..?!

Comment: edit yout question adding that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place all your code inside `$(function(){})` (shorthand for `$(document).ready()`) so you aren't getting any DOM elements before they are loaded. You also need to give your `.burger-lines` span and your `.backtotop` button a higher `z-index` than your preloader section (otherwise they can't be clicked).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56e08dzc/

Comment: @rgj No problem.